# Why am I getting an error on null-valued expression?

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new to power shell scripting. I am trying to write a script that will update the BIOS of several hundred Dell computers. But I am having an issue with these two errors:

> ```
> Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace "root\DCIM\SYSMAN"
> At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Bios Updates Test.ps1:4 char:17
> + ... SVersion = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\DCIM\SYSMAN -Class DCIM_BIO ...
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
> ```

and

> ```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Bios Updates Test.ps1:12 char:5
> +  if($BIOSVersion.CompareTo($BIOSUpdateFileVersion) -eq 0)
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

My code is:

```
$ScriptFolder = Split-Path -Parent 
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Model = $((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem).Model).Trim()
$BIOSVersion = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\DCIM\SYSMAN -Class 
DCIM_BIOSElement).Version           

if(Test-Path -Path $ScriptFolder\$Model)
{
  $BIOSUpdateFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $ScriptFolder\$Model
  $BIOSUpdateFileVersion = $BIOSUpdateFile.ToString() -replace ($BIOSUpdateFile.Extension,"")
  $BIOSUpdateFileVersion =  $BIOSUpdateFileVersion.Substring($BIOSUpdateFileVersion.Length -5)                   

  if($BIOSVersion.CompareTo($BIOSUpdateFileVersion) -eq 0)
  {
    Write-Output "BIOS Version is up to date"
  }
  else
  {
    try{
      Write-Output "BIOS Update Needed. Attempting BIOS Flash Operation..."
      #Invoke-Expression $ScriptFolder\$Model\$BIOSUpdateFile " /quiet"
      $objStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
      $objStartInfo.FileName = "$ScriptFolder\$Model\$BIOSUpdateFile"
      $objStartInfo.Arguments = "-noreboot -nopause -forceit"
      $objStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
      [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($objStartInfo) | Out-Null
    }
    catch {[Exception]
      Write-Output "Failed: $_"
    }
  }            

  Write-Output "End Dell BIOS Update Operation. Completed"
}
else
{
  Write-Output "Model Not Supported"
}
```

Comment: You need to address the first error, stating that `ROOT\DCIM\SYSMAN` is not a valid NameSpace. The problem is that you are querying for something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This Dell site describes how to test to see that OMCI is installed.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/4573.omci-from-command-line

```
PS C:\src\t> wmic /namespace:\\root\dcim\sysman path __namespace
Node - CC0xxxxxx
ERROR:
Description = Invalid namespace
```

Are you required to dig into the DELL OMCI namespace? Would the following be of any use?

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\CIMV2' -Class CIM_BIOSElement

SMBIOSBIOSVersion : 68ICE Ver. F.42
Manufacturer      : Hewlett-Packard
Name              : Default System BIOS
SerialNumber      : 5CB3310PDF
Version           : HPQOEM - f
```

And, given that CIM is the future:

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_BIOSElement

SMBIOSBIOSVersion : 68ICE Ver. F.42
Manufacturer      : Hewlett-Packard
Name              : Default System BIOS
SerialNumber      : 5CB3310PDF
Version           : HPQOEM - f
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting an error on null-valued expression?

The error message says `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` The method on the null-valued expression is `$BIOSVersion.CompareTo($BIOSUpdateFileVersion)`. Thas is, because `$BIOSVersion` is an unassigned variable (`null`).

Why is that? If you try to assign the variable, `Get-WmiObject` throws an error, because it couldn't find the namespace. So, in order to fix the second error, you have to assign the variable properly, hence find a proper namespace and/or WMI class.